# Qt: How to avoid signal recursion when updating UI from data

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, game-development

I'm working on an editor for a game.
One of the things I want to do is I want to display the information about a game object and have it updated if anything changes in the game.

Pseudocode:

```
struct GameObject
{
  //Some data over here
  void AddDataListener(DataListener);
};

class GameObjectPanel:QWidget, DataListener
{
  void Initialize()
  {
    //Create all UI elements and setup signals for them, this is called once when window first appears
    //signals are setup so they call various versions of OnValueChanged()

  }

  void SetGameObject(GameObject*)
  {
    //Update the UI elements with the values from the game object
  }

  void OnDataChanged(GameObject*)
  {
    //Update all UI elements
  }

  slot OnValueChanged(...)
  {
    //Update the object
  }
};
```

Now here's the problem: Each time OnValueChanged() gets called, it applies the change to the game object, which then notifies the panel that it changed, which then updates all of the UI elements, which calls OnValueChanged(), which then changes the object, etc.

Luckily this loop doesn't happen in perpetuity, since the values stabilize pretty quickly (the main culprit is the transform, I have a widget that displays the global transform, but I store the local transform, so it needs to re-calculate each time the global transform widget gets changed), but imo the loop shouldn't happen at all.

Is there a way to subscribe to slots but only have them activate if it was the user changing the data, or is there a way to just enable/disable all the slots at once? going through each connection one by one and disabling them and then re-enabling them doesn't seem very viable to me, since there's quite a lot of them, and it would be easy to miss.

My current solution involves adding a "blockGameObjectSignals" bool which I set each time I receive a value change signal, and each time I update from game object, but that's a lot of extra code that's very repetitive and easy to screw up, so would be nice to know if there's a "proper" way to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Generally you try to avoid emitting a signal if the data isn't really different from what it was before. `void setData(int value) { if (m_value != value) { m_value = value; emit dataChanged(); }}`

Comment: @JarMan the issue with that is that the data is different if the object changes.
ie: Object changes->Requests UI to change->UI data is different -> Requests object to change ->Due to insufficient precision data in UI is different from data in object -> object changes etc.
I would need to display 10 decimal points (my world transforms are doubles) for the UI and data to have the same data, or I would need to create a copy of the entire object contents. Neither of which is practical.

Comment: You can compare `double`s (for equality) with `|a - b| <= epsilon` where `epsilon` will define the accuracy of the comparison (if all number were exactly representable as doubles, then epsilon would be zero, but it's an ideal world XD )

Answer (score 2):

In either of your methods: `OnDataChanged` or `OnValueChanged` you can use [QSignalBlocker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsignalblocker.html) on the considered objects to prevent them from emitting `***changed` signals.

It's a common practice for UI elements that that have cyclic dependencies to each other, e.g. DEC->HEX and HEX->DEC converter with 2 `QLineEdit`, one of them changes as you type in the other.

Comment: @pptashni Would I call this on just my GameObjectPanel, or would that have to be done for each UI element? (I'm assuming each element since otherwise any widget inside of my panel would lose communication between its own internal ui elements)

Comment: It depends on the exact login in both of your callbacks. From your description it seems to me that you can do it in 2 ways: in `OnDataChanged` block all UI elements that you interact with (in that callback), or in `OnValueChanged` block your `GameObject`. Try the 1st option just in case, because I don't know how complex your `GameObject` is.